# What happens when you initialize a const reference by conversion constructor?

Tags: c++

What happens when you initialize a const reference by conversion constructor? Is it any different from an ordinary assignment? Look at this code:

```
void func(const char* cstr) {
    std::string S1 = cstr;
    const std::string& S2 = cstr;
}
```

Is there any practical difference between S1 and S2? Why would you want to use the second expression?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any practical difference between S1 and S2?

In terms of performance, the answer is no. Both instructions invoke *converting constructor* and allocate memory, then copy the the `char` array in the internal dynamic memory of `std::string` instance.

In term of syntax, the answer is obviously the `const`-ness: in the successive block of the function the object handled by `S2` cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1):

- With `std::string S1 = cstr;`

  `S1` is move-constructed from a temporary. That move-construct should probably be elided, but should be accessible. As not `const`, `S1` can be modified.
- With `const std::string& S2 = cstr;`

  `S2` is a const reference to a temporary string, with extended lifetime. As `const`, `S2` cannot be modified.

For type without move/copy constructor as

```
struct S {
    S() = default;
    S(const S&) = delete;
    S& operator =(const S&) = delete;
};
```

You may use the second form, but not the first one:

```
 S s1 = S{}; // Invalid
 const S& s2 = S{}; // Valid
 S&& s3 = S{}; // Valid too.
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a `const` reference to the S1 string, and the compiler enforces the `const` of the value. If you try to modify `S2` it will not compile. For local variables it doesn't make much sense, except when you don't trust yourself to not modify `S2`, or when you are doing code refactorings moving things around and you want to be sure that `S2` is never changed.

But if you pass a string as an argument to a function you can use a `const` reference to avoid a costly copy:

```
void f(const std::string& S2) { ... }
```

`const` in general won't help the compiler to perform optimizations to the code since you can always use `const_cast` to remove the `const` of a variable.